# How to check the docker-compose logs when started with detached mode?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running 2 apps with docker-compose. How to see the logs when I start them in detached mode like

`docker-compose up -d`

Where do I access the logs for docker-compose output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view all logs:

```
docker-compose logs
```

To view and follow all logs:

```
docker-compose logs -f
```

View last 50:

```
docker-compose logs --tail 50
```

View last 10 and follow:

```
docker-compose logs --tail 10 -f
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the logs, cd in to the directory where the docker-compose.yml is and then use `docker-compose logs -f -t`